# How to make button disappear in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make Tic Tac Toe game and I want to button disappear when it's clicked, I searched on SO and I have this code but it doesn't work, why? Idk. Code:

```
def hide_me(event):
    event.widget.grid_forget()

def callback(Buttons):
   Buttons.bind('<Button>', hide_me)


def callback_and_hide(button):
    callback(Play_Button1)
    button.grid_forget()

Play_Button1 = Button(master = window,text='ㅤㅤ',command=lambda: callback_and_hide(Play_Button1))
Play_Button1.config(bg="white",fg="black")
Play_Button1.place(x=54, y=157, width=61, height=61)
```

Comment: Im fairly certain that its because you are putting the button onto the screen with place but then trying to use grid_forget. you should be using place_forget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using `grid`, so calling `grid_forget()` will have no effect. Each of the geometry managers have their own variations, and you must use the one related to the geometry manager you're using:

- `grid_forget`
- `grid_remove`
- `pack_forget`
- `place_forget`